# Autocorrelation for a continuous time stochastic process

Tags: probability, self-study, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes

I have a question involving this (specifically the auto-correlation part):

[image]

My question is: Why is there a dirac delta function instead of an indicator function (i.e. the dirac function is "infinity" when the argument is zero, whereas the indicator function is 1 - for this case - when the argument is zero)?

Intuitively, it seems that when `t` and `tau` are equal, then the expected value of `w(t)*w(tau)` should just be the variance (or the variance times 1, which would be reflected in the indicator function). Instead, in this example, it's the variance times "infinity".

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: This is not a Dirac delta: it's merely an indicator, equal to $1$ when $t=\tau$ and $0$ otherwise.  This surely was explained earlier in the document.

Comment: @whuber For _continuous_ time white noise processes, the autocorrelation function does involve a Dirac delta (whose Fourier transform is a constant). What I don't understand is what that $q(t)$ is doing there.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I should have included more info, but that `q` is just the variance. The notes go on to say it doesn't have a dependence on time, so they just leave it as `q`. Also, could you provide more info on why it involves a dirac delta? Or is the definition for the expected value for continuous stochastic variables just different from discrete ones?

Answer (score 3):

The defining equations for the (continuous-time) white noise process are incorrect: the white noise model corresponds to a weakly stationary (or
wide-sense-stationary) process and the autocorrelation function must be
$$E[w(t)w(t+\tau)] = K \delta(\tau), -\infty < t, \tau < \infty
\tag{1}$$ 
where $\delta(\tau)$ is indeed the Dirac delta. Note that I do not
say Dirac delta *function* because $\delta(\tau)$ is not a *function*
in the sense that it is *not* a mapping $\tau \mapsto \delta(\tau)$. Thus, $\delta(1)$ or $\delta(0)$ does not stand for a number, and 
it is not
correct to say that $\delta(1) = 0$ or that $\delta(0)$ is "infinity."
Suffice it to say that for all practical purposes (for engineers
such as myself, at least), the Dirac delta belongs only inside
an integral, and its defining property is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\delta(t)\,\mathrm dt = g(0)
~ \text{provided that}~ g(t)~ \text{is continuous at}~ t=0.\tag{2}$$
This *sifting* integral can be manipulated according to the usual
rules regarding change of variables in integrals and thus, subject to the
continuity constraints, we have that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\delta(t-\tau)\,\mathrm dt = g(\tau)\tag{3}$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\delta(at)\,\mathrm dt
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|a|}g(\tau/a)\delta(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau = \frac{g(0)}{|a|}\tag{4}$$
etc. Finally, I will add that the above calculations also
hold when the integrals are not over the entire real line but
over an interval that includes the point where the Dirac delta
argument equals $0$, that is,
$$\int_a^b g(t)\delta(t-\tau)\,\mathrm dt =
\begin{cases} g(\tau), & \tau \in (a,b)\\0, & \tau \notin (a,b)\end{cases}
\tag{5}$$

---

Turning to the problem at hand, you have a particle that (without loss
of generality) is at the origin at $t=0$ and moves with constant velocity
$v_0$ (which needs to be specified as an initial condition) along
the $x$ axis. This is in the absence of any noise: the acceleration
is defined to be $0$. When the acceleration is a deterministic
function $y(t)$, say, the
velocity at time $t$ is given by
$$v(t) = v_0 + \int_0^t y(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau \tag{6}$$
If the acceleration is a wide-sense-stationary
*random* process $y(t)$, then
$(6)$ is a stochastic integral and $v(t)$ is a *random variable*.
In fact, the *ensemble* of random variables $\{v(t) \colon t \geq 0\}$
is a *random process*.  I will simply state (without providing
a justification) that subject to some constraints, it is possible
to interchange the order of taking the expectation and
the integration and write 
$$E[v(t)] = E\left[v_0 + \int_0^t y(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\right]
= v_0 + \int_0^t E[y(\tau)]\,\mathrm d\tau = v_0.\tag{7}$$
if $\{y(t)\}$ is a zero-mean process. More generally, for a zero-mean
wide-sense-stationary input process,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(v(t)) &= E[(v(t)-v_0)^2]\\
&= E\left[\int_0^t y(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\int_0^t y(\nu)\,\mathrm d\nu\right]\\
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t E[y(\tau)y(\nu)]\,\mathrm d\tau\,\mathrm d\nu\\
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t R_y(\tau-\nu)\,\mathrm d\tau\,\mathrm d\nu\\
&= \int_{-t}^t (t-|\lambda|)R_y(\lambda)\,\mathrm d\lambda\tag{8}
\end{align}
where $R_y(\cdot)$ is the autocorrelation function of the input
process.

**Finally,** when the input process is a white noise
process with autocorrelation function $K\delta(\tau)$, we
get from $(5)$ and $(8)$ that the velocity $v(t)$ is a
*random variable* with mean $v_0$ and variance $Kt$. Note that
the *ensemble* $\{v(t)\colon t \geq 0\}$ is *not* a 
wide-sense-stationary process (the variance is an increasing
function of time). If the input process is a *Gaussian*
white noise process, then **the velocity**
$v(t)$ is a Gaussian random variable
and $\{v(t)\colon t \geq 0\}$ is a continuous-time random
walk (sometimes called a Brownian motion) that starts at
$v_0$. The *location* of the particle is the integral of this
Brownian motion.

Comment: +1 Thank you for such a clear explanation.  I was finally convinced that the OP must have meant the Dirac distribution, rather than the Kronecker delta, once I re-read the part about *constant* (presumably nonzero) *power spectral density*: that clinches the argument, because if the Kronecker were actually meant, the power spectrum would be identically zero (and the model would be practically useless).

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is even simpler than what you're explaining. My question is, basically, for a random variable X with mean of 0, when you take the expected value of X*X (the variance of X) the value is sigma^2. However, for the continuous time stochastic variables, it seems the variance of X(t) is sigma^2 times the dirac delta. I'm wondering why this dirac delta suddenly appears... I'm a complete newbie with probability so excuse me if this doesn't appear to make sense to you.

Comment: @jucestain In general, the variance of $X(t)$ is _not_ $\sigma^2$ times a Dirac delta. A random process is a collection of random variables $X(t)$.  Its mean _function_ is $\mu(t) = E[X(t)]$ and its variance _function_ is var$(X(t))$ whatever that variance works out to be. Don't mess around with white noise before understanding random processes. Read [this answer of mine](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235) over on dsp.SE or Appendix A of [this Lecture Note](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf) of mine.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right, I definitely need to read about random processes before touching this stuff (I thought I could just get by with a basic understanding of random variables). Thanks!